# What does this ruby snippet do?

Tags: ruby

As a ruby newbie I am trying to understand a snippet of code in our baseline.  Could someone please do that for me ? The snippet appears below

```
%w{word1 word2}.each { |att| define_method(att.to_sym) { return nil }}
```

Comment: SO is not a great tutorial site. This could be answered with any of the many Ruby resources out there. Start at the beginning with `%w`, a "word array". There are also online Ruby REPLs (https://repl.it/languages/Ruby) that you can use if you can get your irb to work.

Comment: Codestyle recommend using `%w[word1 word2]` instead of `%w(word1 word2)` and `%w{word1 word2}`

Comment: This uses almost every feature in the entire Ruby language, you will have to narrow down your question a *lot* more, otherwise an answer will basically be the entire Ruby Language Specification.

Comment: Though it does not appear to be documented, it seems that `.to_sym` is not necessary here: `define_method("dog") { "woof" }; dog
 #=> "woof"`. This should not be surprising as many Ruby methods that take an argument that is the name of a method accept either a symbol or a string. Notice that there is no need for `return` in the block.

Answer (score 2):

In the context where this line will be run, two methods will be defined

```
def word1
  return nil
end

def word2
  return nil
end
```

For example

```
class MyClass
  %w{word1 word2}.each { |att| define_method(att.to_sym) { return nil }}
end
```

After my_class.rb file will be loaded you will be able to consume generated methods

```
test = MyClass.new
test.word1
# or
test.word2
```

Answer (score 2):

Like [jdv said in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54952016/what-does-this-ruby-snippet-do/54952189#comment96666810_54952016), for tutorials you might be better of on other websites. Here are all references needed to understand the piece of code provided:

- [Percent strings](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Percent+Strings), used in `%w{word1 word2}`

  > #### Percent Strings
  >
  > Besides `%(...)` which creates a [String](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/String.html), the `%` may
  >   create other types of object. As with strings, an uppercase
  >   letter allows interpolation and escaped characters while a
  >   lowercase letter disables them.
  >
  > These are the types of percent strings in ruby:
  >
  > - **`%i`:** [Array](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Array.html) of Symbols
  > - **`%q`:** [String](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/String.html)
  > - **`%r`:** Regular Expression
  > - **`%s`:** [Symbol](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Symbol.html)
  > - **`%w`:** [Array](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Array.html) of Strings
  > - **`%x`:** Backtick (capture subshell result)
  >
  > For the two array forms of percent string, if you wish to
  >   include a space in one of the array entries you must escape
  >   it with a “\” character:
  >
  > ```
  > %w[one one-hundred\ one]
  > #=> ["one", "one-hundred one"]
  > ```
  >
  > If you are using “(”, “[”, “{”, “<” you must close it with
  >   “)”, “]”, “}”, “>” respectively. You may use most other
  >   non-alphanumeric characters for percent string delimiters
  >   such as “%”, “|”, “^”, etc.
- [`Array#each`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Array.html#method-i-each)

  > #### each {|item| block} → ary
  >
  > #### each → Enumerator
  >
  > Calls the given block once for each element in `self`,
  >   passing that element as a parameter. Returns the array
  >   itself.
  >
  > If no block is given, an [Enumerator](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Enumerator.html) is returned.
  >
  > ```
  > a = [ "a", "b", "c" ]
  > a.each {|x| print x, " -- " }
  > ```
  >
  > produces:
  >
  > ```
  > a -- b -- c --
  > ```
- [`Module#define_method`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Module.html#method-i-define_method)

  > #### define_method(symbol, method) → symbol
  >
  > #### define_method(symbol) { block } → symbol
  >
  > Defines an instance method in the receiver. The *method*
  >   parameter can be a `Proc`, a `Method` or an `UnboundMethod`
  >   object. If a block is specified, it is used as the method
  >   body. This block is evaluated using `instance_eval`.
  >
  > ```
  > class A
  >   def fred
  >     puts "In Fred"
  >   end
  >   def create_method(name, &block)
  >     self.class.define_method(name, &block)
  >   end
  >   define_method(:wilma) { puts "Charge it!" }
  > end
  > class B < A
  >   define_method(:barney, instance_method(:fred))
  > end
  > a = B.new
  > a.barney
  > a.wilma
  > a.create_method(:betty) { p self }
  > a.betty
  > ```
  >
  > *produces:*
  >
  > ```
  > In Fred
  > Charge it!
  > #<B:0x401b39e8>
  > ```
- [`String#to_sym`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/String.html#method-i-to_sym)

  > #### to_sym → symbol
  >
  > Returns the `Symbol` corresponding to *str*, creating the
  >   symbol if it did not previously exist. See `Symbol#id2name`.
  >
  > ```
  > "Koala".intern         #=> :Koala
  > s = 'cat'.to_sym       #=> :cat
  > s == :cat              #=> true
  > s = '@cat'.to_sym      #=> :@cat
  > s == :@cat             #=> true
  > ```
  >
  > This can also be used to create symbols that cannot be
  >   represented using the `:xxx` notation.
  >
  > ```
  > 'cat and dog'.to_sym   #=> :"cat and dog"
  > ```

Answer (score 1):

**`%w{word1 word2}`** = creating an array that looks like this `['word1', 'word2']`
**`.each`** = iterating through each value in the array
**`{}`** = this is a code block each value in the array will be run through this block
**`|attr|`** = block parameter. each value in the array will be placed here
**`define_method`** = define a method from the argument
**`(att.to_sym)`** = the name of the new method. this will be `word1` and then `word2`
**`{ return nil }`** = the body of the new method

So what is happening is you are defining two new methods. One method called `word1` and another called `word2`. Each of these methods will have a body of `return nil`. They will look like this:

```
def word1
  return nil
end

def word2
  return nil
end
```